# List Iterator getting stuck-Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, listiterator

I have a file which has the following data

1^ I hated that phone it never did what i told it to do it was slow response time s**t net          and would constantly crash out on me as I would load too many apps or videos on to the phone i thought i pods where suppose to be for media driven people. if you don't mind your phone locking up or having to factory reset it every few days go for it.#

2^ This device was the first advanced device that actually had a lot to do on it with so little bugs and the best browser of any smartphone. The I phone 3G and 3Gs innovated the way we make smartphones today.#

---

Each line is delimited with a "#" and in each line it is separated by a "^"
I am storing them in a listoflists and printing them.
The code (given below) is printing the 2 lines correctly but gets stuck after that and not exiting. i don't know where the problem is. Please help.

```
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("comments.csv");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(fr);
        sc.useDelimiter("#");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listoflists= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> singlist= new ArrayList<String>();

        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String line=sc.next();
            String[] element=line.split("\\^");
            for( int i=0; i< element.length;i++)
            {
                singlist.add(element[i]);
                bw.write(element[i]);
                bw.newLine();
                //System.out.print(element[i]+"\n");
            }
            listoflists.add(singlist);

        }
    // it running properly till this part without getting stuck in infinite loop
        ListIterator<String> iter1=singlist.listIterator();
        ListIterator<ArrayList<String>> iter2=listoflists.listIterator();
        while(iter2.hasNext())
        {
            while(iter1.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(iter1.next());
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: iter2 is not forwarded; so iter2.hasNext() will be true always. Call iter2.next() somewhere

Comment: Use the foreach loop to avoid such bugs: `for (List<String> singleList : listOfLists) { for (String s : singleList) { ... }}`

Comment: @vpram86 It worked! thanks, but how did the iterator print the second line of the data if the pointer did not forward?(since i got both the lines as output) :/

Comment: The first while is true, so we go the second one. It's also true, so we print the first value, then it's true again, so we print the second value, then it's false, so we go back to the first while, there is nothing else to to do, but it's still true, so we enter it again, but the second while is false, we do nothing and finish the first while, which is still true so we enter it and...

Answer (score 4):

This code is infinite loop:

```
while(iter2.hasNext())
{
    while(iter1.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(iter1.next());
    }
}
```

Because you don't move over `iter2` and it always indicates to first item.

This should fix thre problem:

```
while(iter2.hasNext())
{
    while(iter1.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(iter1.next());
    }
    iter2.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what your trying to do is

```
ListIterator<ArrayList<String>> iter2 = listoflists.listIterator();
while(iter2.hasNext()){
    List temp = iter2.nextElement();
    ListIterator<String> iter1 = temp.listIterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(iter1.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! thanks, but how did the iterator print the second line of the data if the pointer did not forward?(since i got both the lines as output)

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking iter2.next(), so it iterates infinitely.

```
while(iter2.hasNext()) {
   while(iter1.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(iter1.next());
   }
   iter2.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your problem Clearly ,

I think,If you want read your prepared List again than , should read singleList from listoflist

```
    ListIterator<ArrayList<String>> iter2=listoflists.listIterator();
    while(iter2.hasNext())
    {
        ListIterator<String> iter1=(ArrayList<String>)iter2.next();  
        while(iter1.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iter1.next());
        }
```